# В сети Stack Exchange есть другой сайт, более подходящий для этого вопроса

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено

Периодически возникают [вопросы, заданные на английском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/459857/1).

В причинах закрытия есть замечательный пункт, что вопрос принадлежит другому сайту, однако в списке есть только мета. Думаю, было бы неплохо добавить туда английский StackOveflow, чтобы можно было отправлять туда вопросы, заданные на английском.

Comment: В идеале у пользователя должны появляться две кнопки: [Transfer question], [Я переведу вопрос на русский]

Comment: можно было бы выводить какое-нибудь сообщение/предупреждение о том, что вопрос лучше задать на другом сайте SO

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Такая возможность уже есть, но только у модераторов. Модератор может перенести вопрос вообще на любой сайт Сети. Если вы видите подобный вопрос, пожалуйста, отметьте его сигналом тревоги «требует вмешательства модератора».

Comment: <s>Но ведь мета доступна и не для модераторов. Вряд ли кто-то по ошибке на английский сайт пошлёт - я ж не предлагаю всю сеть добавлять</s> Передумал. На английском может быть другой более подходящий сайт, не обязательно enSO. Согласен.

Comment: @Qwertiy Поздний коммент: Я тоже люблю хтмл-ом, но тут можно юникодом зачеркнуть: Н̵о̵ ̵в̵е̵д̵ь̵ ̵м̵е̵т̵а̵ ̵д̵о̵с̵т̵у̵п̵н̵а̵ ̵и̵ ̵н̵е̵ ̵д̵л̵я̵ ̵м̵о̵д̵е̵р̵а̵т̵о̵р̵о̵в̵.̵ ̵В̵р̵я̵д̵ ̵л̵и̵ ̵к̵т̵о̵-̵т̵о̵ ̵п̵о̵ ̵о̵ш̵и̵б̵к̵е̵ ̵н̵а̵ ̵а̵н̵г̵л̵и̵й̵с̵к̵и̵й̵ ̵с̵а̵й̵т̵ ̵п̵о̵ш̵л̵ё̵т̵ ̵-̵ ̵я̵ ̵ж̵ ̵н̵е̵ ̵п̵р̵е̵д̵л̵а̵г̵а̵ю̵ ̵в̵с̵ю̵ ̵с̵е̵т̵ь̵ ̵д̵о̵б̵а̵в̵л̵я̵т̵ь̵ . Потом коммент удалите ;)