# Видит только Мету в разделе "другие сайты Stack Exchange" при оставлении тревоги

Tags: обсуждение, дефект

Несколько минут назад был задан [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1166886/344284), касающийся исключительно математики. Закономерно возникло желание оставить тревогу с меткой "В сети Stack Exchange есть другой сайт, более подходящий для этого вопроса." и, таким образом, посоветовать человеку обратиться на https://math.stackexchange.com/, который, несомненно, более подходит для этого вопроса. Однако в списке возможных сайтов был обнаружен только данный – StackOverflow Meta.

Вопрос: не стоит ли добавить в этот список ВСЕ сайты из сети Stack Exchange, если уж даже название метки явно это предполагает?

P.S. [Данный](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1600/344284) вопрос, по моему мнению, не является дубликатом, т.к. там предлагается добавить в список только англоязычный SO.

Comment: Немного не в тему, но почему Вы решили, что математика не подходит к тематике сайта? У нас это онтопик. [Математике — быть](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8684/339283).

Comment: @nomnoms12, потому что StackOverflow однозначно потеряет свой прежний вид, если начнут появляться вопросы по типу "Как решить квадратное уравнение", "Как взять производную" и прочее в количестве, соизмеримом с количеством вопросов по программированию. Или Вы и такие вопросы считаете уместными для SO? В Stack Exchange есть сайты, посвящённые математике. Так почему не перенаправлять вопросы, по крайней мере, никак не связанные с программированием, туда?

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Что ему там делать, вопрос же на русском.

Comment: Тогда формулировка метки теряет смысл. В таком случае стоит переименовать её во что-то типа "Этот вопрос больше подходит для SO Meta", т.к. нынешнее название вводит в заблуждение.

Comment: @V-Mor, в списке модераторов есть все сайты

Comment: @Grundy, так почему бы не сделать список полным для всех?

Comment: @V-Mor, про это уже спрашивали кстати :-) По-моему в вопросе про перенос на английский SO - в общем это может не правильно использоваться :)